# "java.lang.NullPointerException" error in JMeter Non-Gui mode

Tags: nullpointerexception, jmeter

When I try to execute JMeter (Version **5.1.1** & **5.2.1**) recorded script in Non-Gui mode using distributed testing, It is displaying below shown **"java.lang.NullPointerException"** error while generating HTML report. Also JTL report is creating an empty notepad file without any data.

.

**Note:-** This error occurrs only when I place **CSV Data Set Config** - Config Element in the test plan. When I remove/disable it, HTML and JTL reports get generated without any error. Also I can't skip this CSV Data Set Config plugin on test execution.

.

Please let me know, If there is any other solution to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What are the CSV Data Set Config variables names and values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're highlightling not the cause but rather a consequence, you should be rather paying attention to the [Summariser](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/Summariser.html) output which states `summary = 0`

[image]

which basically means that no [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) were executed so your test script execution on slaves failed somewhere somehow. First of all I would recommend checking `jmeter.log` on the master and `jmeter-server.log` files on the remote machines, most probably you will be able to figure out the root cause from there.

Quick checklist:

1. Make sure to use the same [Java](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) version on the master and the slaves
2. Make sure to use the same JMeter version (better [the latest one](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)) on the master and the slaves
3. If your test relies on [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) - you need to install all the plugins used in the test onto all the slaves
4. If you define some properties in *user.properties* file you need to do the same on all the remote machines (or alternatively pass them via `-G` command-line argument)
5. If you're using external 3rd-party files (CSV files, files to be uploaded, etc.) - you will need to manually copy them to the slave machines
6. Double check [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) to ensure that the slaves can communicate with the master in order to send Sample Results back to it. Also make sure that the relevant ports are open in [Windows Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Firewall)

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Everything is fine except the 5th point. Placed all the csv files in slave machines also, Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems like a with csv file path.Make sure you are providing the correct path in csv-file-config.Normally this happens when it is not able to read the data from the location.